# Getting MySQL error that seems to be unrelated to what I am doing

Tags: php, mysql

I have this MySQL query written in PHP:

```
$insert_suggested_solution_comment = "insert into suggested_solution_comments 
(problem_id , commenter_id, comment, solution_part , date , guid) values ( ".$problem_id." ,  ".$member_id." , '".$comment."' , ".$recent_topic_id.",
NOW() , '".$md5c."' )" ;
```

But the error I get is this one:

```
Field 'suggested_solution_id' doesn't have a default value
```

But how can that be? :) I never reference suggested_solution_id in the query.

I triple-checked and yes, this error does come from this query. Would anyone know why this may be happening?

This is how the table looks like:

```
mysql> describe suggested_solution_comments;
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                 | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| comment_id            | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| problem_id            | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| suggested_solution_id | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| commenter_id          | int(10)        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| comment               | varchar(10000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| solution_part         | int(3)         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date                  | date           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| guid                  | varchar(50)    | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: is 'suggested_solution_id' a NOT NULL field?

Comment: @JeroenJK I just added the description of the table. Does that help?

Comment: Your table makes the problem pretty clear, most fields cannot be `NULL`, yet the default value for all is `NULL`. That's not going to work if you don't send a value. Just set the default to `0` (or something similar) or allow the field to be `NULL`.

Comment: All fields with `Null = NO` MUST contain something. If it has `auto_increment`, it will always have value, but `suggested_solution_id` does not have that. If you want it to be possible for that column to be empty, `Null` should be `YES`. Else, you should ALWAYS give it a value when inserting en row. ---`NOT NULL` means that a field CANNOT be `NULL` (empty)---

Comment: Do you know if this is a new kind of an error that older versions of MySQL wouldn't give? I just updated my MySQL and this started happening.

Comment: There is a bug logged for a similar issue in mysql: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63972 Also please have a look at the link I had provided in the answer. It clearly says why you get this eror. Yes it looks like it's because of the upgrade, but it's a default configuration issue in my.ini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's exactly the problem - you didn't reference `suggested_solution_id`.

`suggested_solution_id` has the `NOT NULL` constraint, and no default value. In your query you create a row without specifying a value for it. MySQL can't put `NULL` in there - since it's a `NOT NULL` field - and it can't give it a default value - since it doesn't have a default value - therefore it complains.

Comment: Do you know if this is a new kind of an error that older versions of MySQL wouldn't give? I just updated my MySQL and this started happening.

Answer (score 2):

Well It looks like suggested_solution_id is the primary key (obviously NOT NULL) and it might not be an AUTO_INCREMENT field. SO you are not inserting a value to that field(Which expects one).

If that's not the case try this [solution](https://www.farbeyondcode.com/Solution-for-MariaDB-Field--xxx--doesn-t-have-a-default-value-5-2720.html).

Comment: Do you know if this is a new kind of an error that older versions of MySQL wouldn't give? I just updated my MySQL and this started happening.